# General help on simplifying an equation (beginner)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm just looking for some help to see if I've simplified this equation properly.  It is from an article that I'm critiquing (listed here: https://grisda.org/assets/public/publications/origins/17056.pdf) and my answer seems to fit what the author has listed.  Basically, I just want to see if my workflow is correct/excessive/etc, as my arithmetic and algebraic skills are not that great, to say the least!  I thank the community in advance for any advice.

**Simplify the following equation $$0.95A_1 = A_1(1 - e^{-a(F-T)})$$ at T = 4000 $$0.95A_1 = A_1(1 - e^{-a(F-4000)})$$ first distribute $A_1$ which gives $$0.95A_1 = A_1 - A_1e^{-a(F - 4000)}$$ then subtract $A_1$ from both sides $$-0.05A_1 =  -A_1e^{-a(F - 4000)}$$ divide both sides by $-A_1$ (this cancels out the term $A_1$) $$0.05 = e^{-a(F - 4000)}$$ since $e$ is being raised to a negative exponent, it can also be expressed as $$0.05=\frac{1}{e^{a(F - 4000)}}$$ now multiply both sides by $(e^{a(F-4000)})$ resulting in $$(0.05)(e^{a(F-4000)}) = 1$$ then divide both sides by $(0.05)$, which yields $$e^{a(F-4000)} = 20$$ take the natural log ($ln$) of both sides $$a(F-4000) = 2.996$$ finally, divide both sides by $(F-4000)$ to simplify for $a$ $$a = \frac{2.996}{(F-4000)}$$**

Comment: You are right. You can simplify the process by first dividing both sides by $A_1$.

Comment: Feedback: (1) $A_1$ can disappear right from the start (divide by $A_1$), it's nuisance if you keep it around. (2) Substitute 4000 only at the end, keep parameters around to avoid calculation mistakes. 
$$0.95A_1=A_1(1-e^{-a(F-T)})$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.95=1-e^{-a(F-T)}$$
Move the exponential on the left, $0.95$ on the right (changing signs)
$$e^{-a(F-T)}=0.05$$
(3) Never calculate $\ln$ until the very end, keep it there.
$$-a(F-T)=\ln(0.05)$$
$$a=-\frac{\ln(0.05)}{F-T}\approx \frac{2.996}{F-4000}$$

Comment: Thank you both.  That makes sense.